# Cardinality of power set and binary sequence

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Let $A$ be a set and $P(A)$ be the power set of $A$. Define $B(A)$ as
>   the set of all functions $F:A\rightarrow\{0,1\}$. For example,
>   $B(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of all binary sequences. Prove that $P(A)$
>   has the same cardinality as $B(A)$.

When $A$ is finite, this is easy to prove. I am interested in other cases; for instance when $A$ is countably infinite or uncountable. I am also a bit confused with the definition of $B(A)$. Could anyone help me with this one please?

Comment: You need to find a bijection between these two sets....

Comment: If $S$ is a subset of $A$ then an obvious map $F$ can be defined concerning the elements of $S$, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bijection is given by defining the function $F_X:A\to\{0,1\}$ with $X\subseteq A$ as:
\begin{align}
F_X(a)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $a\in X$}\\
0&\text{if $a\notin X$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The things you have to show is that $G:\mathcal P(A)\to B(A)$ with $G(X)=F_X$ is a bijection.

Comment: Small typo: it should be $a\in X$ instead of $a\in A$.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano Thanks, I had the roles of $X$ and $A$ reversed initially, seems I missed one

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Consider, for each subset $B$ of $A$, its characteristic function $\chi_B$ defined by
$$
\chi_B(x)= \begin{cases}1&\text{if $x \in B$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$